# Remove coordinate on custom image when it's resized

Tags: javascript, dictionary, coordinates

I have some problem in area coordinate. I have a image of map a plots and i have set coordinates but when i resize the map image then ordinates position change. I want to position same of coordinate when map image increase or decrease. I have attached the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Property Map Detail</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

//style code

```
<style>
 #testing{
   border:4px solid #33B792;
   background:#2f4e5f;
   width:200px;
   min-height:75px;
   height:auto;
   border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   color:#fff;
   text-align:center;
   z-index:999999;
  }
  .traker {
   position:relative;
   cursor:pointer;
   width:15%;
   float:left;
   right:-18px;
   top:-16px;
  }
  #dataSetss{
   padding-top:5px;
   padding-bottom:5px; 
   width:85%;
   float:left;
  }
  </style>
```

//script for alert popup on pointer and fetch data on onclick event by ajax

```
  <script>
  var mouseX,mouseY,windowWidth,windowHeight;
  var  popupLeft,popupTop;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       mouseX = e.pageX;
       mouseY = e.pageY;
       if( this.offsetLeft !=undefined)
         mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
       if( this.offsetTop != undefined)
         mouseY = e.pageY; - this.offsetTop;
       if(mouseX < 0)
            mouseX =0;
       if(mouseY < 0)
           mouseY = 0;
       windowWidth  = $(window).width()+$(window).scrollLeft();
       windowHeight = $(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop(); 
     });
     $("#info").draggable()
   });
   function alertPopup(plotNo,sector,scheme){
     if(plotNo.trim() != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "enquiry_ajax.php",   
            async: true,
            data:"plot="+plotNo+"&sector="+sector+"&scheme="+scheme,
            success: function(result){
                if(result != ''){
                    document.getElementById("dataSetss").innerHTML = result;
                    $('#testing').show();
                    var popupWidth  = $('#testing').outerWidth();
                    var popupHeight =  $('#testing').outerHeight();

                    if(mouseX+popupWidth > windowWidth)
                        popupLeft = mouseX-popupWidth;
                    else
                        popupLeft = mouseX;
                    if(mouseY+popupHeight > windowHeight)
                        popupTop = mouseY-popupHeight;
                    else
                        popupTop = mouseY; 

                    if(popupLeft < $(window).scrollLeft()){
                        popupLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
                    }
                    if(popupTop < $(window).scrollTop()){
                        popupTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                    }
                    if(popupLeft < 0 || popupLeft == undefined)
                        popupLeft = 0;
                    if(popupTop < 0 || popupTop == undefined)
                        popupTop = 0;
                    $('#testing').offset({top:popupTop,left:popupLeft});
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("dataSetss").innerHTML = 'No Record Found';
                    $('#testing').show();
                    var popupWidth  =  $('#testing').outerWidth();
                    var popupHeight =  $('#testing').outerHeight();

                    if(mouseX+popupWidth > windowWidth)
                        popupLeft = mouseX-popupWidth;
                    else
                        popupLeft = mouseX;
                    if(mouseY+popupHeight > windowHeight)
                        popupTop = mouseY-popupHeight;
                    else
                        popupTop = mouseY; 

                    if(popupLeft <  $(window).scrollLeft()){
                        popupLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
                    }
                    if(popupTop < $(window).scrollTop()){
                        popupTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                    }
                    if(popupLeft < 0 || popupLeft == undefined)
                        popupLeft = 0;
                    if(popupTop < 0 || popupTop == undefined)
                        popupTop = 0;
                    $('#testing').offset({top:popupTop,left:popupLeft});
                }
              }
        });
       } else {
         document.getElementById("dataSetss").innerHTML = 'No Record Found';
         $('#testing').show();
      }
   }
   function closePopup(){
     $('#testing').hide(); 
   }
```

//image resize script

```
   $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#zoom-in').click(function () {
        $('#info').width($('#info').width()*1.2)
        $('#info').height($('#info').height()*1.2)
    })
    $('#zoom-out').click(function () {
        $('#info').width($('#info').width()/1.2)
        $('#info').height($('#info').height()/1.2)
    })
  }); 
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="testing"><div id="dataSetss"></div><img src="fancy_close.png" alt="" class="traker" id="trim" onClick="closePopup();"></div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-2 main" style="background:#6898F6; height:100%;">
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="zoom-in"  id="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
  <button class="zoom-out" id="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 sidebar"  style="overflow:scroll; width:80%; height:100%">
```

// Plots map image

```
  <img src="1-b.png" alt="b2" name="info" usemap="#planetmap" id="info" border="0">
</div>
<div>
```

// Area coordinate set

```
<map name="planetmap">
    <area shape="poly" coords="504,1945,504,2052,531,2052,554,2052,572,2052,576,2051,576,2022,576,1973,575,1945" alt="b1" onClick="alertPopup('1','B','1');" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <area shape="poly" coords="582,1947,583,2051,604,2051,622,2051,638,2052,639,1946"   alt="b2"        onClick="alertPopup('2','B','1');"  style="cursor:pointer;">
    <area shape="poly" coords="645,1946,645,2052,704,2051,704,1946"                     alt="b3"        onClick="alertPopup('3','B','1');"      style="cursor:pointer;">
    <area shape="poly" coords="708,1946,708,2052,768,2052,768,1947,772,1946"            alt="b4"        onClick="alertPopup('4','B','1');"      style="cursor:pointer;">
    <area shape="poly" coords="771,1945,771,2051,831,2052,831,1945,836,1945"            alt="b5"        onClick="alertPopup('5','B','1');"      style="cursor:pointer;">
    <area shape="poly" coords="836,1945,837,2052,896,2052,896,1947,900,1945"            alt="b6"        onClick="alertPopup('6','B','1');"      style="cursor:pointer;">
    <area shape="poly" coords="900,1945,900,2051,960,2053,960,1946"                     alt="b7"        onClick="alertPopup('7','B','1');"      style="cursor:pointer;">
    <area shape="poly" coords="965,1948,965,2053,1024,2054,1024,1948"                   alt="b8"        onClick="alertPopup('8','B','1');"      style="cursor:pointer;">
    <area shape="poly" coords="1028,1945,1029,2053,1088,2053,1088,1947"                 alt="b9"        onClick="alertPopup('9','B','1');"      style="cursor:pointer;">
    <area shape="poly" coords="1092,1946,1092,2051,1152,2053,1152,1947"                 alt="b10"       onClick="alertPopup('10','B','1');"     style="cursor:pointer;">
   <area shape="poly" coords="1156,1947,1156,2052,1216,2052,1216,1946"                  alt="b11"       onClick="alertPopup('11','B','1');"     style="cursor:pointer;">
</map>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can help me. I want that my coordinate position remain same when its resize.
Thanks 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b6d6.png)

Comment: Anyone can help me to set the position of coordinate when image resized...